# Facebook API through Android and login into Symfony2

Tags: android, facebook, symfony, authentication

I've got an app on Android which I got access to my profile, but with that data (may be access_token?) I'd like to do login into my Symfony2 project without any kind of password. Or should I do the login through Symfony2 and the interaction betwen the Android App and my Symfony2 project?

What should I do?

Anyway thanks for anyone for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the graph API from facebook

From the android application, you get the access_token from the sdk.
And to get a token from your SF2 application, You call the /login/facebook?token=[access_token] api.

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token;
$response = $this->wget($url);
$data = json_decode($response['content'], true);
if(isset($data['error'])){ 
    // if the response has errors
    throw new HttpException(self::ERROR_CODE, $data['error']['message']);
} else if(isset($data['verified']) && $data['verified'] == true){

    // Your user is successfully authenticated, you can retrieve is personal information from $data
    // What you get depend of your FB app permissions

} else {
    throw new HttpException(self::ERROR_CODE, self::ERROR_INVALID_FACEBOOK_USER_MESSAGE);
}
```

wget util here:

```
private function wget($url)
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```